# stackpanel xml parsed targets to go to a new row

Tags: wpf, xaml, stackpanel

I have a stackpanel, this stackpanel is used to populate xml parsed targets as a checkbox as shown.

```
    foreach (var child in stack1.Children)
    {
        if ((child is System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox) && ((System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox)child).IsChecked.Value)
        {
            masterbuildproperties.WriteLine(((System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox)child).Tag);
        }
    }
```

This stackpanel is embedded in a grid control.
XAML:

```
<StackPanel Name="stack1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    </StackPanel>
```

My question is, how do i ensure that after 7 checkboxes have been parsed, my 8th checkbox and above will go to a new row? Example as shown below:

```
checkbox1 checkbox2 checkbox3 checkbox4 checkbox5 checkbox6 checkbox7

checkbox8 checkbox9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Wrap Panel](http://www.wpftutorial.net/WrapPanel.html) to achieve this.